# Error while converting my eel python project to .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, eel

I have made a single page project eel where I take the user id and print it in python whenever the person clicks on the button. It runs smoothly on normal run in vs code. But when I converted it to .exe file It is throwing me error. I have tried pyinstaller as well as auto-py-to-exe but it is giving me same following error whenever I opens the .exe file.
 `Traceback (most recent call last): File "ex.py", line 1, in <module> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module File "eel\__init__.py", line 15, in <module> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>`
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Can you please help me with it to solve my problem.....

I am trying to convert my eel python project to an executable file but it is giving me error whenever I runs the .exe file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your script :

```py
import ctypes

def hideConsole():
  whnd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
  if whnd != 0:
     ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(whnd, 0)

hideConsole()
```

and build without '--noconsole' option